# Is it possible with igraph in R to delete subgraphs that do not meet certain conditions?

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph

I want to create a subgraph that includes all the clusters/groups that consists out of at least one red and one green node. However, the clusters should still include the grey nodes, in case there are grey nodes in a particular cluster as well.

```
library (igraph)

#### Random graph #####
set.seed(123) #reproduction
g <- erdos.renyi.game(75,1/75, directed =  F, loops = F)

#### simple random sample from graph object #####
set.seed(123) #reproduction
smpl1 <- sample(1:vcount(g),20)
smpl2 <- sample(1:vcount(g),20)

##### add colours #####
V(g)$color = "green"
V(g)[smpl1]$color = "red"
V(g)[smpl2]$color = "grey"

set.seed(123) #reproduction
plot(g,
     vertex.label.color = "Black",
     vertex.size = 10,
     layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g))
```

The expected output, using the code above, is one plot which includes the remaining (four) clusters that have at least one green and one red node.

Comment: You say "I want to create a subgraph that includes all the clusters/groups that consists out of at least one red and one green node.".  When you say cluster do you mean connected component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "I want to create a subgraph that includes all the clusters/groups that consists out of at least one red and one green node.",  I assume that you mean connected components. So restating, you want the subgraph induced by all grey nodes together with those nodes in connected components that contain at least one red and one green node.

It is not too hard to do this. First compute the connected components. Make a list of the nodes to keep and generate the subgraph.

```
CG = components(g)
KeepNodes = which(V(g)$color == "grey")
for(i in 1:max(CG$membership)) {
    CompNodes = which(CG$membership == i)
    if(any(V(g)$color[CompNodes] == "green") + 
        any(V(g)$color[CompNodes] == "red") == 2) {
        KeepNodes = union(KeepNodes, CompNodes) }
}
SubGraph = induced_subgraph(g, KeepNodes)
plot(SubGraph)
```

[image: sub-graph]